# Simplify variadic template: Remove some specializations

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I found a template to calculate the binomial coefficient, which I happily used for function generation. The advantage is that I use this template for compile time Bernstein polynomial generation instead of using the derived polynomials (just 5 very simple ones).

I initially thought the code would become easier by doing so because the generation of the five random functions now obvious. Unfortunately, the code below is hard to read for someone not used to templates. Is there a way to get rid of at least some of the template specializations?

```
// Template functions to estimate the binominal coefficient
template<uint8_t n, uint8_t k>
struct binomial {
  static constexpr int value = (binomial<n - 1, k - 1>::value + binomial<n - 1, k>::value);
};

template<>
struct binomial<0, 0> {
  static constexpr int value = 1;
};

template<uint8_t n>
struct binomial<n, 0> {
  static constexpr int value = 1;
};

template<uint8_t n>
struct binomial<n, n> {
  static constexpr int value = 1;
};
```

Comment: Any templating code is going to be hard to read for a person that doesn't know templates. I dont think this code is hard to read at all and is actually quite clean.

Comment: Constexpr functions?

Comment: If you want to keep the templates (and not go for the more readable constexpr functions as some have suggested), I believe that the `binomial<0, 0>` is a specific case of `binomial<n, n>`. So you could drop the former, reducing the number of specializations to just 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might probably use *constexpr* functions. Here is *C++11*-friendly version:

```
constexpr int factorial(int n)
{
    return (n == 1) ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1);
}

constexpr int bin_coeff(int n, int k)
{
    return factorial(n) / factorial(n - k) / factorial(k);
}
```

[**EXAMPLE**](https://godbolt.org/g/xwqdLU)

Comment: Care with `constexpr` functions, as they can be "misused" and computed at runtime: `std::cout << factorial(5)` vs `constexpr auto fac_5 = factorial(5);`